# sidebar multi level animated dropdown menu in vanilla js

Tags: javascript, css, animation

**For Bounty**

I search it on google to find library something like but I did not find... if anyone knows you can give as an answer  (only vanilla js library & MIT license )...

Otherwise do not change html structure... fixing  my code it will be  better for me.. otherwise you can resolve your own way ..

**End Bounty**

```js
const dataKeys = document.querySelectorAll('nav ul')
dataKeys.forEach(function(el,key){
    el.setAttribute('data-key',key);
})


const lists = document.querySelectorAll('ul ul')
lists.forEach(function(el){
    let sh = el.scrollHeight;
    el.setAttribute('data-sh',sh);
    el.classList.add('sub-menu')
    el.style.maxHeight =  0 + "px"; 
})
document.querySelectorAll("ul li").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
    try {
      let el = e.target.parentElement.children[1]; 
      let ul = e.target.parentElement.closest('ul');
      if(ul){
        ul.querySelectorAll('ul').forEach(function(item){
          item.style.minHeight = 0 + 'px';
        })
      }
      if(parseInt(getComputedStyle(el).minHeight) > 0){
        el.style.minHeight = 0 + "px";
      }else{
        el.style.minHeight =  el.scrollHeight + "px";
      }
    } catch (error) {
      return false;
    }
     return false;
}));



  document.querySelectorAll("ul ul li").forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();

    // const lists = document.querySelectorAll('ul ul')
    // lists.forEach(function(el){
      
    //     el.style.minHeight =  0 + "px"; 
    // })

    let el = null;
    let sh = 0;

     if(e.target.parentElement.hasChildNodes()){
      let ul = e.target.parentElement.querySelector('ul');
      if(e.target.parentElement.contains(ul)){
        el = e.target.parentElement.children[1];
        console.log(e.target.parentElement);
        console.log(e.target.parentElement.children[1]);
        sh  = el.scrollHeight;
      }
    }
      
    
      let elKey = parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-key'));

      let elli = e.target.parentElement.parentElement;

      let elH =  parseInt(el.getAttribute('data-sh'));
      let elliH =  parseInt(elli.getAttribute('data-sh'));

      // elli.style.minHeight = 0 + 'px';
      
      let elFirstChild = 0;
      if(el.hasChildNodes()){
        elFirstChild = el.children[0].scrollHeight;
        elFirstChild = parseInt(elFirstChild);
      }
    
      elli.style.minHeight = elliH + elFirstChild - elH + 'px';
      el.style.minHeight = elH + 'px';

     return false;
  }));
```

```css
a {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 5px 10px;

    color: white;
}

nav ul,
nav ul ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
    width: 200px;
    background: dodgerblue;
    position: relative;
}


nav ul ul {

    background: rgb(13, 130, 141);
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px dashed white;
    transition: min-height .5s ease-in-out;

}

nav ul ul ul {
    background: rgb(1, 8, 8);
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px dashed white;

}

nav ul ul ul ul {
    background: rgb(10, 41, 179);
    margin-left: 15px;
    border-left: 1px dashed white;
}
```

```html
  <nav>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dropdown 1 </a>
                <ul class="label-one">
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Menu 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a>
                        <ul class="label-two">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a>
                        <ul class="label-two">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 4</a>
                        <ul class="label-two">
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                            <!-- <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li> -->
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dropdown 2 </a>
                <ul class="label-one" >
                    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2 </a>
                        <ul >
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
                            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </nav>
```

Comment: will this work for u

Comment: @Ac_mmi  this is not what I am looking for ..

Comment: what is what you are looking for

Comment: In my code you can use class drop to add submenu and place it after the anchor tag that will onclick show it

Comment: @Ac_mmi if you click on `Dropdown 1` and `Dropdown 2`  in my question snippet , you will see how it's work..

Comment: you want one dropdown opened at a time

Comment: @Ac_mmi if you click on `Dropdown 1`  then if   `Dropdown 2 ` already opened it will close  . same think will happen when i click on `Dropdown 2`  then if   `Dropdown 1 ` opened  it will close.. i write about it on my question like `toggle`..

Comment: i worked on my code, saw your output and realised that you wanted not more than one subdivisions in a single level to appear i made it again(also changed the output gif) this will work for you, you just need to place the 'drop' div right after the anchor tag through which you want the submenu to be opened

Comment: @Ac_mmi I appreciate your worked... why did not you used `ul` & `li` ?  and when I click on `Dropdown 1  > Menu 1`   `Menu 2` not close or toggle

Comment: i haven't added any submenus to menu 1 in dropdown 1 i added submenus to menu2 and 3 you can see my output gif only those are the submenus which can be expanded i haven't added submenus to all button

Comment: @Ac_mmi first click on   `menu 2` then click on `menu 1`, you will see that `menu 2` will not close or toggle...

Comment: i haven't added any submenus to menu1 so if someone clicks it would load another page but if you add submenus then it would respond as per your requirement see now i have  added drop class after menu 1

Comment: see the output now

Comment: I will not reload page ..  something like component ... okay...

Comment: alright i will rectify this flaw

Comment: will this work for u

Answer (score 4):

### This is what i could make so far if it works for you i could make it in more tidy manner(I'll try)

here i made a div of class drop where we can add `<a>` tags

[image]

```js
function onLoad() {

  var drop = document.getElementsByClassName('drop');
  var adj_flag = 0;
  var Height = 0;
  var array = [];
  var c = [];
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
  var d;


  for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
    if (a[i].nextElementSibling != "DIV") {
      a[i].onclick = function() {
        var p = this.parentElement.children;
        for (var j = 0; j < p.length; j++) {
          if (p[j].nodeName == "DIV") {
            var decre = style_length(p[j].style.height);

            if (decre > 0) {
              p[j].style.height = "0px";
              var div = p[j];
              while (div.parentElement.nodeName == "DIV") {

                div = div.parentElement;

                div.style.height = (style_length(div.style.height) - decre) + "px";

              }
              var query_div = p[j].querySelectorAll("*");
              for (var k = 0; k < query_div.length; k++) {
                if (query_div[k].nodeName == "DIV") {
                  if (style_length(query_div[k].style.height) > 0) {
                    query_div[k].style.height = "0px";
                  }
                }
              }

            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < drop.length; i++) {

    drop[i].style.height = '0px';
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < drop.length; i++) {



    drop[i].previousElementSibling.onclick = function() {
      if (this.nextElementSibling.nodeName == "DIV") {
        var elem = this.nextElementSibling;

        var height_div = 0;
        if (elem.style.height == "0px") {
          var check = elem.parentElement.children;

          for (var i = 0; i < check.length; i++) {
            if (check[i].nodeName == "DIV" && check[i] != elem) {
              if (check[i].style.height != "0px") {

                c.push(check[i].previousElementSibling);


              }
            }
          }


          var height_calc = elem.children;
          for (var i = 0; i < height_calc.length; i++) {
            if (height_calc[i].nodeName == "A") {
              height_div += 38;
            }
          }


          elem.style.height = height_div + 'px';
          var flag = 0;
          var add_h = height_div;
          var changes;
          var q;
          if (c.length > 0) {

            for (var i = 0; i < c.length; i++) {
              if (style_length(c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height) != 0) {
                if (style_length(elem.style.height) == style_length(c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height)) {
                  changes = 0;
                } else {
                  if (style_length(elem.style.height) < style_length(c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height)) {
                    add_h -= style_length(c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height);
                  } else {
                    add_h -= style_length(c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height);
                  }

                }
              }
              c[i].nextElementSibling.style.height = "0px";
              q = c[i].nextElementSibling.querySelectorAll("*");
              for (var k = 0; k < q.length; k++) {
                if (q[k].nodeName == "DIV") {
                  q[k].style.height = "0px";
                }
              }
            }
          }

          while (elem.parentElement.nodeName == "DIV") {
            elem = elem.parentElement;
            var h = elem.offsetHeight + add_h;
            elem.style.height = h + 'px';

          }

          c.pop();

          flag = 0;
        } else {
          var query = elem.querySelectorAll('*');


          var sub_h = elem.clientHeight;
          elem.style.height = "0px";
          while (elem.parentElement.nodeName == "DIV") {
            elem = elem.parentElement;
            var h = elem.clientHeight - sub_h;
            elem.style.height = h + 'px';
          }

          for (var i = 0; i < query.length; i++) {
            if (query[i].nodeName == "DIV") {


              query[i].style.height = "0px";
            }
          }


        }
      }
    }
  }

  function style_length(A) {
    A = A.substring(0, A.length - 2);
    var s = parseInt(A);
    return s;
  }

}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  color: white;
  font-family: 'arial';
}

.menu {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 250px;
  min-height: 114px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: black;
}

.menu a {
  background-color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
}

.drop {
  background-color: black;
  transition: height 0.4s;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: 15px;
  height: 0px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="onLoad()">
  <nav class="menu">
    <a href="#/">HOME</a>
    <a href="#/">DropDown-1</a>
    <div class="drop">
      <a href="#/" style="background-color: #00175A;">MENU-1</a>

      <a href="#/" style="background-color: #00175A;">MENU-2</a>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-1</a>
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-2</a>
        <div class="drop">
          <a href="#/" style="background-color:grey;">submenu-1</a>
          <a href="#/" style="background-color:grey;">submenu-2</a>
          <a href="#/" style="background-color:grey;">submenu-3</a>
        </div>
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-3</a>
        <div class="drop">
          <a href="#/" style="background-color:grey;">submenu-1</a>
          <a href="#/" style="background-color:grey;">submenu-2</a>
        </div>

      </div>
      <a href="#/" style="background-color: #00175A;">MENU-3</a>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-1</a>
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-2</a>
      </div>

    </div>
    <a href="#/">DropDown-2</a>
    <div class="drop">
      <a href="#/" style="background-color: #00175A;">MENU-2</a>
      <div class="drop">
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-1</a>
        <a href="#/" style="background-color: #030E2E;">SUBMENU-2</a>
      </div>

    </div>

  </nav>
</body>
```

Comment: Your example is great! But the codes seem complex to me to understand what's happening there. Could you please retouch your codes so that others (like me) can use this in their project as a multi-level dropdown menu with minimal modification? Maybe just putting the top most ul class?

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelectorAll('li').forEach(element => element.addEventListener('click', event => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();

  let innerLists = element.querySelector('ul');
  if (innerLists) {
    if (!innerLists.classList.contains("show-list")) {
      document.querySelector("ul").querySelectorAll("ul").forEach(elm => {
        if (!isDescendant(elm, element)) {
          elm.classList.remove("show-list")
        }
      });
    }

    innerLists.classList.toggle("show-list");
  }
}));

function isDescendant(parent, child) {
  let node = child.parentNode;
  while (node != null) {
    if (node === parent) {
      return true;
    }
    node = node.parentNode;
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
a {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px !important;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  color: white;
}

nav ul,
nav ul ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  overflow: hidden;
}

nav ul {
  width: 200px;
  background: dodgerblue;
}

nav ul ul {
  background: rgb(13, 130, 141);
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  /* height: 10px; */
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul ul ul {
  background: rgb(1, 8, 8);
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  /* height: 10px; */
  transition: max-height .5s ease-in-out;
}

nav ul ul ul ul {
  background: rgb(10, 41, 179);
  margin-left: 15px;
  border-left: 1px dashed white;
  /* height: 10px; */
  transition: max-height 0.5s ease-out;
}

ul li ul {
  max-height: 0 !important;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}

.show-list {
  max-height: 500px !important;
  transition: max-height 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dropdown 1 </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> Menu 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 3</a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 1 Sub Menu 3</a> </li> -->
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Dropdown 2 </a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0)">Menu 2 </a>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2 Sub Menu 1</a></li>
            <li><a href="javascript:void(0)"> 2 Sub Menu 2</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Note:** You don't have to write a lot of this JS code for a simple dropdown task.

Comment: it's not collapse previous  `ul`  list... if you click on `Dropdown 1` and `Dropdown 2` in my question snippet , you will see how it's work..

Comment: @noor Now check

Comment: firstly thanks for response ...  but   animation properly not working .. if you compare with my example `Dropdown 1` and `Dropdown 2`.. I think you can figure it out... this the one reason i wrote many code.. maybe there is alternative way..

Comment: Please check again

Comment: you use `max-height: 500px !important;` , it will create bug if more `li` item exist ...